# in vuejs, input event fire isn't working inside a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the last version of vuejs. I'd like to fire an event as soon as the input is changed by the user

I tryied two approach :

1. try to launch an event as soon as the value change (@change="modifie")
2. try to rely on the data of the json (it should be transformed if there is a two way databinding)

(I prefer the first approach, I have only one value to check)

Tks

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        vuepanier = new Vue({
            el: '#panier',
            data: {
                panier: [{"id":"1612","qty":3},{"id":"1614","qty":1}]
            },
            methods: {
                modifie: function(event, id) {
                alert(id);
                },
            supprime: function(event, id) {
                alert(id);
            }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="panier">
            <div v-for="item in panier">
                <input type="number" v-bind:id="'spinnermod' + item.id" v-bind:value="item.qty"><br/>
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-sm text-white texteopaque' v-on:click="supprime($event, item.id);">delete</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe take a look at computed: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html I use them for this type of thing. The link above gives you an example of how they work.

Comment: What problem are you trying to fix? Events are what we're trying to get away from, so if you can watch your model, not your DOM input, that's usually a much better way. The only valid reason to watch the input is to update the model.

Comment: @change seems to be working fine.Its not included in your code but I tried it on jsfiddle with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to fire an event as soon as the input is changed by the user

to fire an event as soon as the input is changed, you can simply use `v-on:input`, or `@input` in the `<input/>`

Is this what you looking for?

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        vuepanier = new Vue({
            el: '#panier',
            data: {
                panier: [{"id":"1612","qty":3},{"id":"1614","qty":1}]
            },
            methods: {
                modifie: function(event, id) {
                alert(id);
                },
            supprime: function(event, id) {
                alert(id);
            }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="panier">
            <div v-for="item in panier">
                <input @input="supprime($event, item.id)" type="number" v-bind:id="'spinnermod' + item.id" v-bind:value="item.qty"><br/>
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-sm text-white texteopaque' v-on:click="supprime($event, item.id);">delete</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello i use the wrong @property. Thanks for your help. Do you know why bi directionnal doesn't work ?

Comment: what do you mean by bi directionnal? can you explain more?

Comment: when I modify the input, I'd like to know how I can apply the modifications on the json file.